# Joycons buzzing in Portal Knights on Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, portal-knights

I recently started Portal Knights on the Nintendo Switch and I noticed that when I use my "Stone Pickaxe" on things, both joycons vibrate loudly, like a buzzing noise.

**Is this normal?** I tried two sets of joycons and it does happen on both. For an action that is so common, I worry that it'll ultimately ruin the motors in the joycons.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely normal. Almost all of the games for the Switch have something that makes the joy-cons vibrate. I'm sure it won't ruin your joy-cons. If you want to turn off vibration, go to system settings. Go down until you see **Controllers and Sensors** on the left side. Click it and go down to **Controller Vibration** and select it. It will turn off your vibration. Here's a picture of what it looks like. It's a bit blurry, but it's the best I could find. It should suffice.

[image]

Comment: I guess my comment was moreso saying that the vibration was extreme. It's like the vibrate for that game was pushing the limits of what it should be vibrating at. Other games aren't nearly as loud. I did manage to disable vibrations specifically for that game.